# Matlab Not Working

Tags: matlab

I have a Ubuntu 12.10. I have Matlab 2012b installed on it.It was working fine until the last time I tried to open it.

**My Problem : ** Matlab not working.The following message is displayed when I open it through terminal.I am new to ubuntu and I need help to resolve it.

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
what():  locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: If the problem only occurred once rebooting the computer may help.

Comment: Thanks but I observed that there was some libraries that went missing after some updates which I have to add on separately.Now its working fine.

Comment: Could you please briefly describe how you did it and accept that as an answer? This may help others who encounter the same problem.

Comment: Honestly I am not sure of how it was fixed.I took help of my friend.All I got was that some libraries related to locale were missing after some updates.They were restored again manually.I am sorry that I don't remember the exact command used.

Answer (score 1):

As the asker seems to have found a solution I will post it here for him:

> some libraries related to locale were missing after some updates.They
>   were restored again manually.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how or why, but running software updates and following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095645/running-mongodb-on-ubuntu) similar post's answer did the trick for me.
That is to add this environment variable...

```
export LC_ALL=C
```

Have a nice week.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and resolved it by setting a locale explicitly in the GUI according to the instructions [here](https://wiki.debian.org/Locale), though on my build (debian 7.6) the appropriate panel item was at the top of the screen. It was then necessary to log out and back in again to make it take effect.

This assumes you have the underlying locales installed and configured properly on the base system, which you can do in a shell with

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

NB That same document recommends not to use the LC_ALL environment variable on the grounds that it's a high level override of all the other locale settings intended for testing purposes.